# can someone please elaborate the following code?

Tags: java

This code is the first one I've seen. I am curious as to how it changes all character from a to z into uppercase when the last line of code was only written with `(ch[i] - 'a' + 'A')`.

```
if (ch[i] >= 'a' && ch[i] <= 'z') { 
    // Convert into Upper-case 
    ch[i] = (char)(ch[i] - 'a' + 'A'); 
}
```

Comment: what do you think it does?

Comment: The difference between `'a'` and `'A'` is the same as the difference between any lower case letter and its upper case equivalent (in the range of simple `'a'-'z'` characters).

Comment: This also assumes that the letters that are used that require casing are only the [Basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet) letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The line:**

```
ch[i] = (char)(ch[i] - 'a' + 'A');
```

Sets ch[i] to its associated uppercase due to a constant difference between an uppercase letter and its lowercase form.

**For means of communication, the line can be re-written as:**

```
ch[i] = (char)(ch[i] + ('A' - 'a'));
```

By adding this constant difference the line yields the lowercase letter's uppercase character.

Comment: Java uses the UTF-16 character encoding of the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. Any similarity to ASCII is irrelevant.